# create a redirect in drupal root .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, drupal, bitnami

**Environment**: I'm running a Drupal 8 website on a bitnami ec2 stack.

I'm trying to create a redirect Rule. I started with the help of the module https://www.drupal.org/project/htaccess, but for the moment I'm using an SFTP Client to my Ec2 Server and edit the `./apps/drupal/htdocs/.htaccess` file manually.

My goal was to get this url `http://xxx/shop/group/a_name_1234` and redirect to `http://xxx/product?shop=a&productid=1234`. My redirect Rule looked like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9_-]+)/group/a_(.*)_([0-9]+) product?shop=$1&productid=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Since this did not work, I tried a simple redirect from my one site (siteA) to the other site (siteB) of my website

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule siteA siteB
```

But this also doesn´t work.

**Am I using the wrong `.htaccess` file or are my redirects wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

For security and performance reasons, we moved the configuration in the .htaccess files to the main application configuration files and set the AllowOverride option to None by default.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/drupal/administration/use-htaccess/

If you want to add these rules to the Apache's configuration, you can modify 2 different files:

- You can edit the `/opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/conf/httpd-prefix.conf` file and include your rules there
- And you can also edit the `/opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/conf/htaccess.conf` file. That .conf file is added to the Apache's configuration.

I hope it helps,
Jota